# I want to check number of files in specfic folder using Python schedule library or another ways

Tags: python, schedule

I want to number of files in folder every hour

i try to using schedule library in python.

but when it count is changed.

I can not update variable.

please. give some advice.

```
def running(before):

   os.chdir('\\\\111.11.11.11\\d\\Daily')

   files = list( os.listdir() )

   before_count = before

   print('before_count_In : ',before_count)

   after = len(files)

   print('after_count_In : ', after)

   if before_count != after:

      shutil.copy(files[len(files)-1] , 'D:\\D\\test' )  *# This is , I can not updata before variable.*

    print('hello log file is going')





############################################################          



before = os.listdir()

before_count = len(before) 

print('before_count_out : ',before_count)

sd.every(10).seconds.do(running , before_count)

while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    print('hi')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your code like this:

```
def running():


    #os.chdir('\\\\111.11.11.11\\d\\Daily')

    #files = list( os.listdir() )

    #before_count = before

    global before_count
    before_count += 10

    print('before_count_In : ',before_count)

    after = len(files)

    print('after_count_In : ', after)

    if before_count != after:

        shutil.copy(files[len(files)-1] , 'D:\\D\\test' )  # This is , I can not updata before variable.*

        print('hello log file is going')





############################################################          



before = os.listdir()

before_count = len(before) 
global before_count
print('before_count_out : ',before_count)

sd.every(10).seconds.do(running)

while True:
    sd.run_pending()
    print('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple function that counts that number of files and prints it out.

```
def size_dir(): #count number of files

    out = open('dayly.txt','a') 
    fs  = len(list(os.listdir('C:\\temp'))) 

    return out.write(str(fs)+'\n') #add number of files in a new line
```

The schedule was set to every 30 seconds, while I was creating text files in temp dir, the path is designed for windows.

```
schedule.every(30).seconds.do(size_dir)

while 1:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

I've printed the output for you.

[image]